# Clicking on stroke of dynamic path using Selenium

Tags: selenium, svg

In SVG you can have things which are only clickable at the stroke, e.g. because there is no fill or because of [`pointer-events: stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("#path1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click1!")
})
document.querySelector("#path2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click2!")
})
```

```css
#path1:hover {
  stroke: red;
}

#path2:hover {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <path d="M64,116 C100,100 400,100 96,39" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7" fill="none" id="path1" />
  <path d="M134,186 C100,100 400,100 126,69" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7" fill="none" id="path2" />
</svg>
```

In my project I want to write Selenium tests for I have a dynamically generated SVG `<path>`s which I want to click at using Selenium, the problem is that the center of the element<sup>1</sup> is not necessarily clickable (since only the stroke of the path is).

#### Some ideas I had:

- **Clicking at a fixed offset:** A possibility but since the generated path is highly dynamic it would mean a lot of tinkering with the offset value to get it right and possibly having to change the test a lot of the future.
- **Triggering click event through code:** Would work but make the test less useful since this way it would not test whether the stroke of the path is indeed clickable. Certain bugs could evade being detected by the test this way.
- **Setting a non-`none` `fill` through code or replacing/adding filled a rect around the `<path>`:** Setting `fill` might not guarantee either that the center is clickable. A `<rect>` would work but then the clickable areas of multiple paths would overlap which could mean that the wrong path  gets the click.

None of these approaches are ideal. Are there any other possibilities?

(I am using Selenium for Python but I am OK with solutions with Selenium for other programming languages since normally it's easy to port.)

<sub>1) This is the default position Selenium clicks at if using the function where no offset is specified, or rather it's the center of the visible area of the element since the newest version of the WebDriver protocol but in my use case everything can be assumed to be fully visible.</sub>

---

P.S.
Demo showing why setting `fill` to something other than `none` wouldn't help (or `pointer-events` to `all`):

```js
document.querySelector("#path1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click1!")
})
document.querySelector("#path2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click2!")
})
```

```css
#path1:hover {
  stroke: red;
}

#path2:hover {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg height="300" width="300">
  <path d="M64,116 C100,100 400,100 96,39" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7" fill="turquoise" id="path1" />
  <path d="M134,186 C100,100 400,100 126,69" stroke="blue" stroke-width="7" fill="yellow" id="path2" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't know about Selenium but one solution to your problem may be `fill:transparent` or  using a transparent rgb or hsl color: `fill:rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: @enxaneta This was my 3rd idea in the list, does not work for paths. I will edit my post so you can see why.